# Is there a way to let Mathematica use my Windows credentials to access a proxy server?

Tags: windows

With version 10, I get this pop-up window:

[image: Authentication Required]

Is there a way to let Mathematica use my Windows login credentials, as for instance Firefox does?

Comment: maybe at least there is a solution to keep "these values" not only for this session instead of changing the proxy properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same in V9 on my work (can't test V10 right now), and it often seemed to be a problem of a proxy using the NTLM protocol for authentication which Mathematica had difficulties with. I found a solution by installing the debugging proxy [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as an intermediate between Mathematica and the company proxy to do the NTLM talking.

However, I just noticed that if you select "Use the following settings:" in the Internet Connectivity>ProxySettings tab *and leave all the boxes empty* (except the "Port:" boxes which are on 0 by default) everything works without Fiddler. Looks like magic and probably won't work in many cases but might be worth a try.

Comment: does'nt work for me ... leaving the fields empty. I get no window for user and pwd, but I'll get a time out for any operation using internet connection.

Comment: @phab Well, that's a  pity, but as I said it probably won't work in many cases, however, it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit -> Preferences -> Internet Connectivity -> Proxy Settings

switch to "Use the following settings" and try

```
[user]:[pwd]@[Proxyname].[Domain]:[Port]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not quite what I was looking for. Your suggestion would require to save the password in plain text, which I am not happy about. I would also have to change every 90 days, when our security policies require a new password.
Is there no way to pass the windows login credentials as Firefox seems to be able to?

Comment: @AxelF The Fiddler reference in my answer does that. In fact I do not even have my own password as we work with a card+PIN combination, with password hidden to the user. Fiddler uses Microsoft's single sign on (SSO) mechanism to identify to the proxy without having to know the password.