# How to access a password-protected ssh server using PowerShell in Mathematica?

Tags: windows, command-line, webservices

I want to run Windows PowerShell commands via Mathematica. Specifically, I need to access a `ssh` server which is password-protected. When I do this using the PowerShell, I get the following prompt

[image]

where I can then type my password. However, while using `RunProcess` in Mathematica, I do not get any password requests and the evaluation does not end. Any way around this?

Here is my code, which works for any other PowerShell commands, inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75703/running-powershell-commands-in-mathematica),

```
shell[s_] := RunProcess[{"powershell", s}, "StandardOutput"]
shell["ssh [user]@[domain]"]
```

for which the second evaluation does not end. How can I overcome this, somehow introducing the password, and access the server? I am also aware of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61486/is-there-a-way-to-let-mathematica-use-my-windows-credentials-to-access-a-proxy-s), but it does not really help me. Any ideas?

**Update:** The server has now imposed a Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) process for which I need to introduce an OTP (following the password), adding to the problem. However, I think a solution to the first issue might potentially also fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you _actually_ want to achieve? The title asks for "running PowerShell", but in the body of the question you ask about how to log in with ssh, but without saying what you want to do once you've logged in. Presumably, you want to run a command. The "right way" to do that is to (1) set up public key authentication (2) run `ssh user@domain command` directly, and do not use PowerShell. Recent versions of Mathematica even have built-in tools to make this much simpler, see e.g. `RemoteRunProcess[]`.

Comment: In summary, this reads like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please update the question and explain what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edited the question. Hopefully now it is more clear. I am not familiar with setting up public key authentication. I have not attempted any solution.

Comment: I run commands remotely from Windows with ssh very frequently using `RemoteRunProcess`. **It works great**. You have to make sure to add your private key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file in the server. I can expand but this is not the question as it doesn't use PowerShell.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino what does adding the private key actually do? Does it store it so I do not get the password request each time I need to access the server? With Mathematica, the problem seems to be precisely in getting the second (password) and third (MFA) inputs via `RemoteRunProcess`.

Comment: I am not sure if removing the need of entering the ssh password will also skips the MFA, but you can try. For this copy the public (not private, my mistake) key from `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "ApplicationData", "SecureShellLink", "Keys"}]` to a file named authorized_keys in the .ssh directory in your home directory in the server. It is just one line so you can just copy and paste it or do `echo "the key" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 2):

## WindowsPowerShell

```
powershell = FileNameJoin[
    {
        Environment["SystemRoot"]
        , "system32"
        , "WindowsPowerShell"
        , "v1.0"
        , "powershell.exe"
    }
]

session = StartExternalSession[{"Shell", "Target"-> powershell}];
```

Now you have a session you can run anything you do in a shell

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "ping google.com"]
```

> ```
> Pinging google.com [142.250.178.14] with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 142.250.178.14: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=57
> Reply from 142.250.178.14: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=57
> Reply from 142.250.178.14: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=57
> Reply from 142.250.178.14: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=57
>
> Ping statistics for 142.250.178.14:
>     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>     Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 4ms
> ```

Including SSH sessions, like with [plink](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (part of [putty](https://www.putty.org/)) which does allow using the password as a command-line parameter.

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "plink demo@test.rebex.net -pw password"]
```

Other ways to avoid typing a password, like using [Public cryptographic keys](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication), are [well documented](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D%20%5Bssh%5D%20authentication), and explaining in detail not within the scope of *Mathematica StackExchange*.

## [`RemoteRunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoteRunProcess.html)

You can avoid going through a `"Shell"` by using [`RemoteRunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoteRunProcess.html) or access remote files using [`RemoteFile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoteFile.html)

```
RemoteRunProcess[
    "test.rebex.net"
    ,"ls -la readme.txt"
    , Authentication -> <|
        "Username" -> "demo",
        "Password"->"password"
    |>
]
```

> ```
> <|
>     "ExitCode" -> 127
>     , "StandardOutput" -> "-rw------- 1 demo users        405 Dec 17  2021 readme.txt"
>     , "StandardError" -> "ls: error in `ls': Path contains invalid characters"
> |>
> ```

## Streams with [`StartProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html)

In principle one could also do

```
proc = StartProcess[{powershell,"-NonInteractive"}];
WriteLine[proc, "ssh demo@test.rebex.net"];
```

and read the outputs with

```
ReadString[ProcessConnection[proc, "StandardError"],EndOfBuffer] 
ReadString[proc, EndOfBuffer]
```

But I didn't manage to craft an example because of the error

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

I trust the other two solutions should be enough.